# What Does CV2's detectMultiScale Method Return?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

In CV2, I am able to generate faces from an uploaded image.

```
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    read_img,
    scaleFactor = 1.1,
    minNeighbors = 0,
    minSize=(100,100)
)
how_many_faces = len(faces)
```

*how_many_faces* returns the correct number of faces.

If I append these faces to an array ...

```
our_faces = []
for i in faces:
    our_faces.append(i)

return str(our_faces)
```

...and return *our_faces*, I get the following data:

> [array([187, 138, 236, 236], dtype=int32), array([197, 138, 236, 236],
>   dtype=int32), array([163, 130, 260, 260], dtype=int32), array([163,
>   141, 260, 260], dtype=int32), array([173, 141, 260, 260],
>   dtype=int32), array([184, 141, 260, 260], dtype=int32), array([143,
>   119, 286, 286], dtype=int32), array([167, 119, 286, 286],
>   dtype=int32), array([143, 131, 286, 286], dtype=int32), array([155,
>   131, 286, 286], dtype=int32), array([167, 131, 286, 286],
>   dtype=int32), array([144, 105, 315, 315], dtype=int32), array([157,
>   105, 315, 315], dtype=int32), array([131, 118, 315, 315],
>   dtype=int32), array([144, 118, 315, 315], dtype=int32), array([157,
>   118, 315, 315], dtype=int32), array([170, 118, 315, 315],
>   dtype=int32), array([130, 87, 346, 346], dtype=int32), array([115,
>   101, 346, 346], dtype=int32), array([130, 101, 346, 346],
>   dtype=int32), array([144, 101, 346, 346], dtype=int32), array([159,
>   101, 346, 346], dtype=int32), array([130, 115, 346, 346],
>   dtype=int32), array([ 87, 70, 419, 419], dtype=int32)]

Am I right to assume that this array contains all the data for each face, and that it is a Numpy array? If so, **how can I convert this data in the array back to an image format?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`faceCascade.detectMultiScale()` returns a list of rectangles so it does not contain the images of the detected faces and you cannot reconstruct the faces purely from that list.

If you want to get images of the faces, you will need to:

- retain a copy of the image in which you originally sought the faces, and
- use Numpy slicing or similar to extract the rectangles whose bounds are in the `faces` list returned by `faceCascade.detectMultiScale()`

Comment: Thanks Mark. That answers the theory-part of things. I was able to get a more reasonable output by using img = Image.fromarray(...), but I'm getting a ValueError that there is "not enough image data". I think it's better asked in a different question, so I'll create a separate question for that error.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep an eye out for the new one. It's no problem, questions are free!

Answer (score 1):

```
def crop(image, faces, k=0):
"""
This function crops the initial image into faces' images seperately. 
Arguments:
    image  (np array image)
    faces (list of tuples)
"""
faces_arrays = []
for (top, right, bottom, left)in faces:
    x0, y0 = left, bottom
    x1, y1 = right, top
    w, h = right-left, top-bottom
    cv2.rectangle(img=image, pt1=(x0, y0), pt2=(x1, y1), color=(255,0,0), thickness=2)
    x2, x3 = x1-w,  x0+w
    # crop the region of interest over a copy 
    face = image[y1:y0, x2:x3].copy()
    faces_arrays.append(face)
    # comment the two following lines if you want to stop saving the crops
    cv2.imwrite('face'+str(k)+'.jpg', face)
    k += 1
return faces_arrays
```